# awk remove substring using regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sh

i have a pipe delimited file that looks like this:

```
34ab1 | aaa bbb   ccc   fff  vf | 2015-01-01
35ab1 | aaa bbb   ccc dddefd ddff  ssss   fff  vi | 2015-01-01
```

i want to replace everything that starts with bbb and ends with fff.

i used this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "|"
}
{
   sub(/[0-9].*[0-9]/, "", $2); sub(/bbb.*fff/, "", $2);
   print
}
```

the regex part for the numbers worked but the second part of the regex didnt.

output i want:

```
34ab1 | aaa   vf | 2015-01-01
35ab1 | aaa   vi | 2015-01-01
```

Comment: But there is no number present in your second column.

Comment: the numbers part is what i used for other rows. it worked so now i added another `sub()`

Answer (score 2):

Use a single gsub function for both.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "|"
}
{
gsub(/[0-9].*[0-9]|bbb.*fff/, "", $2);
print
}
```

Comment: if i have both digits and substring i want to remove in a row, will the `|` in the gsub only replace one of them or both since the`|` means `or`

Comment: No, `gsub` replaces all matches on a line, not just the first.

Comment: will this work if bbb or fff are chinese characters? i tried it but it didnt quite work